# Updating state when state is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with 3 input fields as sender, receiver, and message, form is inside for loop with a unique id:

now I want to update the state when entering form fields , my expected state like below

```
[
    {id: 1, sender: "", receiver: "", message: ""},
    {id: 2, sender: "", receiver: "", message: ""},
    {id: 3, sender: "", receiver: "", message: ""},
]
```

I tried the below code,

```
 const [giftMessages, setGiftMessages] = useState([
        { id: '', sender: '' , receiver: '', giftmsg: '' }
    ]);
    
    
const handleGiftMessages = (e, orderItemId) => {
    const updateMessages = [
        ...giftMessages,
        {
            id : orderItemId,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    ];
    setGiftMessages(updateMessages);
}
```

but it's not coming my expected state format

Comment: Would you mind if you could create a sandbox on `codesandbox`?

Comment: i tried in react stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cqyc1v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
const arr1 = [{ oid: 11 }, { oid: 12 }, { oid: 13 }];
const [giftMessages, setGiftMessages] = useState([]);

const handleGiftMessages = (e, orderItemId) => {
    setGiftMessages(prevGiftMessages => {
        const existingItem = prevGiftMessages.find(item => item.id === orderItemId);
        return (!existingItem
            ? [
                    ...prevGiftMessages,
                    { id: orderItemId, sender: "", receiver: "", giftmsg: "" }
              ]
            : prevGiftMessages
        ).map(giftMessage => {
            if (giftMessage.id === orderItemId) {
                return {
                    ...giftMessage,
                    id: orderItemId,
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
                };
            }
            return giftMessage;
        });
    });
};
```

Code sandbox => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-val2gy?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: what is prevGiftMessages  ? where I declare?

Comment: No need to declare it. it is a input to callback function. prevGiftMessages is the initial state for the very first first time which is `[ { id: '', sender: '' , receiver: '', giftmsg: '' } ]`

Comment: yes i tried same. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cqyc1v

Comment: @GOOG, updated the answer. had to change the initial state like I have given

Comment: its working fine. but initially I don't know the arr1 value. arr1 value coming from api response.

Comment: @GOOG, again updated the answer. now it should work as you expected !! please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!